# Integer factorization: How to explain those numbers?

Tags: number-theory, functions, integers

I am getting a non primary number $d$ with two nontrivial factors and I am trying to find what they are. Basically I am trying to solve the Integer Factorization Problem in special case.

I want to show you my idea for solution, to show you what I found, and then I need your help to analyze this data, this will help me to solve the problem and calculate my solution efficiency.

### The Idea

Start looking on the values $f(x) = \left\lfloor\sqrt{d}\right\rfloor + x$ and find when $d \mod f(x) = 0$

It sounds like something very hard to find, so I just started to look at the numbers and I found some thing interesting, let me show you.

Here is how $f(x)$ for $d = 886139 = 907 * 977$ looks like.

In each row the first value is $f(x)$, second one is $d \mod f(x)$, lets call it $m$, and third one, is where things gets interesting, it's $d \mod f(x + 1) - d \mod f(x)$. Let's call the third value $c$.

```
942   658   1      
943   659   3      
944   662   5      
945   667   7      
946   674   9      
947   683   11     
948   694   13     
949   707   15     
950   722   17     
951   739   19     
952   758   21     
953   779   23     
954   802   25     
955   827   27     
956   854   29     
957   883   31     
958   914   33     
959   947   ############# 940   
960   23    36     
961   59    38     
962   97    40     
963   137   42     
964   179   44     
965   223   46     
966   269   48     
967   317   50     
968   367   52     
969   419   54     
970   473   56     
971   529   58     
972   587   60     
973   647   62     
974   709   64     
975   773   66     
976   839   68     
977   907   ############# 940   
978   0     71     ***** 
979   71    73     
980   144   75     
981   219   77     
982   296   79     
983   375   81     
984   456   83     
985   539   85     
986   624   87     
987   711   89     
988   800   91     
989   891   93     
990   984   ############# 940   
991   89    96     
992   185   98     
993   283   100    
994   383   102    
995   485   104    
996   589   106    
997   695   108    
998   803   110    
999   913   ############# 940   
1000  26    113    
1001  139   115    
1002  254   117    
1003  371   119    
1004  490   121    
1005  611   123    
1006  734   125    
1007  859   127    
1008  986   ############# 940   
1009  107   130    
1010  237   132    
1011  369   134    
1012  503   136    
1013  639   138    
1014  777   140    
1015  917   ############# 940   
1016  44    143    
1017  187   145    
1018  332   147    
1019  479   149    
1020  628   151    
1021  779   153    
1022  932   ############# 940   
1023  65    156    
1024  221   158    
1025  379   160    
1026  539   162    
1027  701   164    
1028  865   ############# 940   
1029  3     167    
1030  170   169    
1031  339   171    
1032  510   173    
1033  683   175    
1034  858   ############# 940   
1035  1     178    
1036  179   180    
1037  359   182    
1038  541   184    
1039  725   186    
1040  911   ############# 940   
1041  59    189    
1042  248   191    
1043  439   193    
1044  632   195    
1045  827   197    
1046  1024  ############# 940   
1047  177   200    
1048  377   202    
1049  579   204    
1050  783   206    
1051  989   ############# 940   
1052  146   209    
1053  355   211    
1054  566   213    
1055  779   215    
1056  994   ############# 940   
1057  155   218    
1058  373   220    
1059  593   222    
1060  815   224    
1061  1039  ############# 940   
1062  204   227    
1063  431   229    
1064  660   231    
1065  891   ############# 940   
1066  59    234    
1067  293   236    
1068  529   238    
1069  767   240    
1070  1007  ############# 940   
1071  179   243    
1072  422   245    
1073  667   247    
1074  914   ############# 940   
1075  89    250    
1076  339   252    
1077  591   254    
1078  845   ############# 940   
1079  23    257    
1080  280   259    
1081  539   261    
1082  800   263    
1083  1063  ############# 940   
1084  245   266    
1085  511   268    
1086  779   270    
1087  1049  ############# 940   
1088  234   273    
1089  507   275    
1090  782   277    
1091  1059  ############# 940   
1092  247   280    
1093  527   282    
1094  809   284    
1095  1093  ############# 940   
1096  284   287    
1097  571   289    
1098  860   ############# 940   
1099  53    292    
1100  345   294    
1101  639   296    
1102  935   ############# 940   
1103  131   299    
1104  430   301    
1105  731   303    
1106  1034  ############# 940   
1107  233   306    
1108  539   308    
1109  847   ############# 940   
1110  48    311    
1111  359   313    
1112  672   315    
1113  987   ############# 940   
1114  191   318    
1115  509   320    
1116  829   ############# 940   
1117  35    323    
1118  358   325    
1119  683   327    
1120  1010  ############# 940   
1121  219   330    
1122  549   332    
1123  881   ############# 940   
1124  92    335    
1125  427   337    
1126  764   339    
1127  1103  ############# 940   
1128  317   342    
1129  659   344    
1130  1003  ############# 940   
1131  219   347    
1132  566   349    
1133  915   ############# 940   
1134  133   352    
1135  485   354    
1136  839   ############# 940   
1137  59    357    
1138  416   359    
1139  775   361    
1140  1136  ############# 940   
1141  359   364    
1142  723   366    
1143  1089  ############# 940   
1144  314   369    
1145  683   371    
1146  1054  ############# 940   
1147  281   374    
1148  655   376    
1149  1031  ############# 940   
1150  260   379    
1151  639   381    
1152  1020  ############# 940   
1153  251   384    
1154  635   386    
1155  1021  ############# 940   
1156  254   389    
1157  643   391    
1158  1034  ############# 940   
1159  269   394    
1160  663   396    
1161  1059  ############# 940   
1162  296   399    
1163  695   401    
1164  1096  ############# 940   
1165  335   404    
1166  739   406    
1167  1145  ############# 940   
1168  386   409    
1169  795   ############# 940   
1170  37    412    
1171  449   414    
1172  863   ############# 940   
1173  107   417    
1174  524   419    
1175  943   ############# 940   
1176  189   422    
1177  611   424    
1178  1035  ############# 940   
1179  283   427    
1180  710   429    
1181  1139  ############# 940   
1182  389   432    
1183  821   ############# 940   
1184  72    435    
1185  507   437    
1186  944   ############# 940   
1187  197   440    
1188  637   442    
1189  1079  ############# 940   
1190  334   445    
1191  779   ############# 940   
1192  35    448    
1193  483   450    
1194  933   ############# 940   
1195  191   453    
1196  644   455    
1197  1099  ############# 940   
1198  359   458    
1199  817   ############# 940   
1200  78    461    
1201  539   463    
1202  1002  ############# 940   
1203  265   466    
1204  731   468    
1205  1199  ############# 940   
1206  464   471    
1207  935   ############# 940   
1208  201   474    
1209  675   476    
1210  1151  ############# 940   
1211  419   479    
1212  898   ############# 940   
1213  167   482    
1214  649   484    
1215  1133  ############# 940   
1216  404   487    
1217  891   ############# 940   
1218  163   490    
1219  653   492    
1220  1145  ############# 940   
1221  419   495    
1222  914   ############# 940   
1223  189   498    
1224  687   500    
1225  1187  ############# 940   
1226  464   503    
1227  967   ############# 940   
1228  245   506    
1229  751   ############# 940   
1230  30    509    
1231  539   511    
1232  1050  ############# 940   
1233  331   514    
1234  845   ############# 940   
1235  127   517    
1236  644   519    
1237  1163  ############# 940   
1238  447   522    
1239  969   ############# 940   
1240  254   525    
1241  779   ############# 940   
1242  65    528    
1243  593   530    
1244  1123  ############# 940   
1245  411   533    
1246  944   ############# 940   
1247  233   536    
1248  769   ############# 940   
1249  59    539    
1250  598   541    
1251  1139  ############# 940   
1252  431   544    
1253  975   ############# 940   
1254  268   547    
1255  815   ############# 940   
1256  109   550    
1257  659   552    
1258  1211  ############# 940   
1259  507   555    
1260  1062  ############# 940   
1261  359   558    
1262  917   ############# 940   
1263  215   561    
1264  776   ############# 940   
1265  75    564    
1266  639   566    
1267  1205  ############# 940   
1268  506   569    
1269  1075  ############# 940   
1270  377   572    
1271  949   ############# 940   
1272  252   575    
1273  827   ############# 940   
1274  131   578    
1275  709   ############# 940   
1276  14    581    
1277  595   583    
1278  1178  ############# 940   
1279  485   586    
1280  1071  ############# 940   
1281  379   589    
1282  968   ############# 940   
1283  277   592    
1284  869   ############# 940   
1285  179   595    
1286  774   ############# 940   
1287  85    598    
1288  683   600    
1289  1283  ############# 940   
1290  596   603    
1291  1199  ############# 940   
1292  513   606    
1293  1119  ############# 940   
1294  434   609    
1295  1043  ############# 940   
1296  359   612    
1297  971   ############# 940   
1298  288   615    
1299  903   ############# 940   
1300  221   618    
1301  839   ############# 940   
1302  158   621    
1303  779   ############# 940   
1304  99    624    
1305  723   ############# 940   
1306  44    627    
1307  671   629    
1308  1300  ############# 940   
1309  623   632    
1310  1255  ############# 940   
1311  579   635    
1312  1214  ############# 940   
1313  539   638    
1314  1177  ############# 940   
1315  503   641    
1316  1144  ############# 940   
1317  471   644    
1318  1115  ############# 940   
1319  443   647    
1320  1090  ############# 940   
1321  419   650    
1322  1069  ############# 940   
1323  399   653    
1324  1052  ############# 940   
1325  383   656    
1326  1039  ############# 940   
1327  371   659    
1328  1030  ############# 940   
1329  363   662    
1330  1025  ############# 940   
1331  359   665    
1332  1024  ############# 940   
1333  359   668    
1334  1027  ############# 940   
1335  363   671    
1336  1034  ############# 940   
1337  371   674    
1338  1045  ############# 940   
1339  383   677    
1340  1060  ############# 940   
1341  399   680    
1342  1079  ############# 940   
1343  419   683    
1344  1102  ############# 940   
1345  443   686    
1346  1129  ############# 940   
1347  471   689    
1348  1160  ############# 940   
1349  503   692    
1350  1195  ############# 940   
1351  539   695    
1352  1234  ############# 940   
1353  579   698    
1354  1277  ############# 940   
1355  623   701    
1356  1324  ############# 940   
1357  671   ############# -415  
1358  18    705    
1359  723   ############# 940   
1360  71    708    
1361  779   ############# 940   
1362  128   711    
1363  839   ############# 940   
1364  189   714    
1365  903   ############# 940   
1366  254   717    
1367  971   ############# 940   
1368  323   720    
1369  1043  ############# 940   
1370  396   723    
1371  1119  ############# 940   
1372  473   726    
1373  1199  ############# 940   
1374  554   729    
1375  1283  ############# 940   
1376  639   732    
1377  1371  ############# 940   
1378  728   ############# -436  
1379  85    736    
1380  821   ############# 940   
1381  179   739    
1382  918   ############# 940   
1383  277   742    
1384  1019  ############# 940   
1385  379   745    
1386  1124  ############# 940   
1387  485   748    
1388  1233  ############# 940   
1389  595   751    
1390  1346  ############# 940   
1391  709   ############# -449  
1392  72    755    
1393  827   ############# 940   
1394  191   758    
1395  949   ############# 940   
1396  314   761    
1397  1075  ############# 940   
1398  441   764    
1399  1205  ############# 940   
1400  572   767    
1401  1339  ############# 940   
1402  707   ############# -460  
1403  75    771    
1404  846   ############# 940   
1405  215   774    
1406  989   ############# 940   
1407  359   777    
1408  1136  ############# 940   
1409  507   780    
1410  1287  ############# 940   
1411  659   ############# -469  
1412  31    784    
1413  815   ############# 940   
1414  188   787    
1415  975   ############# 940   
1416  349   790    
1417  1139  ############# 940   
1418  514   793    
1419  1307  ############# 940   
1420  683   ############# -478  
1421  59    797    
1422  856   ############# 940   
1423  233   800    
1424  1033  ############# 940   
1425  411   803    
1426  1214  ############# 940   
1427  593   806    
1428  1399  ############# 940   
1429  779   ############# -487  
1430  159   810    
1431  969   ############# 940   
1432  350   813    
1433  1163  ############# 940   
1434  545   816    
1435  1361  ############# 940   
1436  744   ############# -494  
1437  127   820    
1438  947   ############# 940   
1439  331   823    
1440  1154  ############# 940   
1441  539   826    
1442  1365  ############# 940   
1443  751   ############# -501  
1444  137   830    
1445  967   ############# 940   
1446  354   833    
1447  1187  ############# 940   
1448  575   836    
1449  1411  ############# 940   
1450  800   ############# -508  
1451  189   840    
1452  1029  ############# 940   
1453  419   843    
1454  1262  ############# 940   
1455  653   ############# -513  
1456  44    847    
1457  891   ############# 940   
1458  283   850    
1459  1133  ############# 940   
1460  526   853    
1461  1379  ############# 940   
1462  773   ############# -520  
1463  167   857    
1464  1024  ############# 940   
1465  419   860    
1466  1279  ############# 940   
1467  675   ############# -525  
1468  71    864    
1469  935   ############# 940   
1470  332   867    
1471  1199  ############# 940   
1472  597   870    
1473  1467  ############# 940   
1474  866   ############# -532  
1475  265   874    
1476  1139  ############# 940   
1477  539   877    
1478  1416  ############# 940   
1479  817   ############# -537  
1480  218   881    
1481  1099  ############# 940   
1482  501   884    
1483  1385  ############# 940   
1484  788   ############# -542  
1485  191   888    
1486  1079  ############# 940   
1487  483   891    
1488  1374  ############# 940   
1489  779   ############# -547  
1490  184   895    
1491  1079  ############# 940   
1492  485   898    
1493  1383  ############# 940   
1494  790   ############# -552  
1495  197   902    
1496  1099  ############# 940   
1497  507   905    
1498  1412  ############# 940   
1499  821   ############# -557  
1500  230   909    
1501  1139  ############# 940   
1502  549   912    
1503  1461  ############# 940   
1504  872   ############# -562  
1505  283   916    
1506  1199  ############# 940   
1507  611   ############# -565  
1508  23    920    
1509  943   ############# 940   
1510  356   923    
1511  1279  ############# 940   
1512  693   ############# -570  
1513  107   927    
1514  1034  ############# 940   
1515  449   930    
1516  1379  ############# 940   
1517  795   ############# -575  
1518  211   934    
1519  1145  ############# 940   
1520  562   937    
1521  1499  ############# 940   
1522  917   ############# -580  
1523  335   941    
1524  1276  ############# 940   
1525  695   ############# -583  
1526  114   945    
1527  1059  ############# 940   
1528  479   948    
1529  1427  ############# 940   
1530  848   ############# -588  
1531  269   952    
1532  1221  ############# 940   
1533  643   ############# -591  
1534  65    956    
1535  1021  ############# 940   
1536  444   959    
1537  1403  ############# 940   
1538  827   ############# -596  
1539  251   963    
1540  1214  ############# 940   
1541  639   ############# -599  
1542  64    967    
1543  1031  ############# 940   
1544  457   970    
1545  1427  ############# 940   
1546  854   ############# -604  
1547  281   974    
1548  1255  ############# 940   
1549  683   ############# -607  
1550  111   978    
1551  1089  ############# 940   
1552  518   981    
1553  1499  ############# 940   
1554  929   ############# -612  
1555  359   985    
1556  1344  ############# 940   
1557  775   ############# -615  
1558  206   989    
1559  1195  ############# 940   
1560  627   ############# -618  
1561  59    993    
1562  1052  ############# 940   
1563  485   996    
1564  1481  ############# 940   
1565  915   ############# -623  
1566  349   1000   
1567  1349  ############# 940   
1568  784   ############# -626  
1569  219   1004   
1570  1223  ############# 940   
1571  659   ############# -629  
1572  95    1008   
1573  1103  ############# 940   
1574  540   1011   
1575  1551  ############# 940   
1576  989   ############# -634  
1577  427   1015   
1578  1442  ############# 940   
1579  881   ############# -637  
1580  320   1019   
1581  1339  ############# 940   
1582  779   ############# -640  
1583  219   1023   
1584  1242  ############# 940   
1585  683   ############# -643  
1586  124   1027   
1587  1151  ############# 940   
1588  593   ############# -646  
1589  35    1031   
1590  1066  ############# 940   
1591  509   1034   
1592  1543  ############# 940   
1593  987   ############# -651  
1594  431   1038   
1595  1469  ############# 940   
1596  914   ############# -654  
1597  359   1042
```

### What I found

So I found that $d \mod f(x) = 0$ only happens when $c$ is odd number. To make it more clear lets call $c$ as $C(x)$ so $C(x) = c$.

I found two things actually $d \mod f(x) = 0$ iff $C(x)$ is an odd number and $C(x - 2)$ is an even number.

Than I been trying to find a function that will represent all the numbers answering the above two conditions:

- $C(x)$ is an odd number
- $C(x - 2)$ is an even number

And I found it! It looks like this:
$$2C(x+1) - C(x) - C(x+2) - x = \left\lfloor\sqrt{d}\right\rfloor)$$

Let $h(x)$ to be the solution to this equation. I found that there is always a solution to $h(x) = d \mod f(x) = 0$(not including the trivial solutions of course).

In the table above I printed s(x) after ######.

### So my question is

How to solve $$h(x) = d \mod f(x) = 0$$

Or in simplified view:

- $r = \left\lfloor\sqrt{d}\right\rfloor$
- $m_1 = d \mod (r + x - 1)$
- $m_2 = d \mod (r + x)$

$$r - 2m_2 + m_1 + x = 0$$

Comment: I don't see how this is "calculus".

Comment: Google `factoring semiprimes`.